# Subdomain redirect for API setup

Tags: api, codeigniter, subdomain

I want to host my API application in a separate server and route it through subdomain fo example `api.example.com`. My domain is hosted at HostGator. I have created a subdomain and redirect it to the API server by providing the IP address.

The application is written in Codeigniter for RestAPI. Whenever I call any API method by referring the subdomain it shows 404 error (`api.example.com/myclass/myfunction`), but if I access the same API using a direct link (`192.0.2.1/myclass/myfunction`) by providing the IP address of the server, it is returning correct result.

Please suggest any configuration change needed.

Comment: `redirect it to the api server by providing the IP address` - how did you do this? Some `.htaccess` rules? Where is your code? What do your routes look like?  Very hard to help when we can't see anything of what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

You can add A record on sub domain, if application is hosted on port 80.

You can simply add A RECORD as

```
192.0.2.1 api.example.com
```

You should have option to create DNS zone on hostgator.